# Checking if a phone number exist in DB crashes app

Tags: android, sqlite, phone-number

In my db manager class I have a function to check if a certain phone number exist in DB:

```
public boolean is_phone_number_exist_in_group(String phone_num, int group_id)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = db_helper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor mContactsCursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_GROUP_CONTACTS, null, 
            "group_id="+group_id+" AND contact_phone="+phone_num, null, null, null, null);

    if(mContactsCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        mContactsCursor.close();
        db.close();
        return true;
    } else {
        mContactsCursor.close();
        db.close();
        return false;
    }

}
```

For now I just want to output the result to logcat:

```
Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "Is Phone number exist: "+manager.is_phone_number_exist_in_group(contact_phone, group_id));
```

But when I run the app - it crashes at this part. This is the output I get in the logcat:

```
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602): java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, 
    data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts/lookup/0r5-49434B2F3D374D4D3D2F/5 flg=0x1 }} 
    to activity {com.myinfo.myapp/com.myinfo.myapp.activities.Activity_Group_Contacts}: 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "444": syntax error: , 
    while compiling: SELECT * FROM group_contacts WHERE group_id=1 
    AND contact_phone=(052) 444-5556
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2980)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602): Caused by: 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "444": syntax error: , while 
    compiling: SELECT * FROM group_contacts WHERE group_id=1 AND 
    contact_phone=(052) 444-5556
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:68)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileSql(SQLiteProgram.java:143)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.compileAndbindAllArgs(SQLiteProgram.java:361)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:127)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:94)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:53)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1564)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1449)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1405)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1485)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at com.myinfo.myapp.tasks.Task_DB_Manager.is_phone_number_exist_in_group(Task_DB_Manager.java:170)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at com.myinfo.myapp.activities.Activity_Group_Contacts.add_new_contact(Activity_Group_Contacts.java:326)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at com.myinfo.myapp.activities.Activity_Group_Contacts.onActivityResult(Activity_Group_Contacts.java:171)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4649)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
09-27 07:55:02.284: E/AndroidRuntime(20602):    ... 11 more
```

My guess, though I'm not sure about it - it's happening either because of the space or the hyphen near the 444 part of the phone number.

How do I fix it and make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just missing quotes around the phone number:

```
Cursor mContactsCursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_GROUP_CONTACTS, null, 
            "group_id="+group_id+" AND contact_phone='"+phone_num+"'", null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: easy solution in the short term, but in the long term, using selectionargs is the recommended path

Comment: Yes indeed, Igal can decide between the 2 options now :)

Answer (score 2):

SQL queries require escaping for certain characters.

In order to avoid worrying about escaping (and also about sql injection), always use the `selectionArgs`. They will be properly escaped by `SQLite`. It also allow `SQLite` to recognize your queries in order to optimize them.

Use like so:

```
String query = "group_id = ? AND contact_phone = ?";
String[] args = new String[] { Integer.toString(group_id), phone_num };
Cursor mContactsCursor = db.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_GROUP_CONTACTS, null, 
        query, args, null, null, null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! The phone number in my question is not a direct user input, it is taken from the Contact URI. So in this case the user doesn't have any access to the DB. But I'm just about to get to part where the user have to make some text input, so I will have to take care of SQL injection and your answer will help me to do so. Upvoted. And thank you again!